# ProgressBar not showing up while waiting for api

Tags: android, api, kotlin, loading, android-progressbar

I'm trying to display a progressbar while the data from the API is fetched, but it never displays. I'm assuming I just have the call for the progressbar in the wrong place but nothing I've done so far has fixed the issue. Below is the code from the activity. 
All I want is for the progressbar to be visible until the data is loaded.

```
package com.hmadland.paranoia
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_profile.*
import org.json.JSONObject
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.hmadland.paranoia.R.layout.activity_profile

class Profile : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
        //get token from login
        val token = intent.getStringExtra("token")
        //get email to find PlayerID in sharedPref
        val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")
        //get PlayerID from sharedPref
        val mypref = getSharedPreferences(email, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val PlayerID = mypref.getString(email, "")
        val progressBar: ProgressBar = this.progressBar1

            // task is run on a thread
            Thread(Runnable {
                // dummy thread mimicking some operation whose progress cannot be tracked


                // display the indefinite progressbar
                this@Profile.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                    progressBar1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                })
                // performing operation
                try {
                    var url = "https://elimination.azurewebsites.net/api/Players/GetPlayer?id="+ PlayerID
                    val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@Profile)

                    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
                            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                            Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
                                //get UserName
                                userName.text = response.get("UserName").toString()
                                //get profile
                                profile.text = response.get("Profile").toString()
                                //get photo
                                Glide.with(this).load(response.get("PhotoUrl")).into(ProfilePic)
                                //round photo
                                Glide.with(this).load(response.get("PhotoUrl")).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ProfilePic)
                            },
                            Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.e("error is ", "" + error) }
                    )

                    //This is for Headers If Needed
                    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                    fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                        params.put("token", token)
                        return params
                    }
                    que.add(jsonObjectRequest)

                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                // when the task is completed, make progressBar gone
                this@Profile.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                    progressBar1.visibility = View.GONE
                })
            }
            ).start()

        ///////////buttons to other views//////////////////////////////
        //go to current target view
        CurrentGame.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, Target::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("token", token)
            intent.putExtra("email", email)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        Inventory.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, com.hmadland.paranoia.Inventory::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        coming.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, UpcomingGames::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

This is the XML from the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hmadland.paranoia.Profile">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="101dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="56dp"
           >


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:padding="10dp"

                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ProfilePic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="132dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="300px"
                android:maxWidth="450px"
                android:minHeight="300px"
                android:minWidth="450px" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/CurrentGame"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round"
                    android:fontFamily="monospace"
                    android:text="Target"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Inventory"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round"
                    android:fontFamily="monospace"
                    android:text="Stats"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/coming"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:shape="oval"
                    android:background="@drawable/round"
                    android:fontFamily="monospace"
                    android:text="Games"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/edit"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round"
                    android:fontFamily="monospace"
                    android:text="Edit"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean Spinner(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner) or ProgressBar?

Comment: You should add your xml layout where you have included progressBar1 and complete code of activity.

Comment: ProgressBar sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the fact that the `Volley.newRequestQueue(this@Profile)` returns a [`RequestQueue`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.java) that enqueues a request to be executed through it's `add` method. The `add` method however immediately returns without waiting for the execution of the call itself.

Since in you code you run the changing of the visibility of the progress-bar directly after the `add` call you probably don't see the bar appear at all (because the whole code runs to fast to notice). What you probably want is to hide the bar in the `Response.Listener` callback (and probably also in the `Response.ErrorListener`) because these are the callbacks that Volley will call on completion (with error or not).

So you enqueue the request and show the progress-bar, when Volley finishes it will let you know through the callbacks and this would be the place to hide the progress-bar again.